# SQL query runs forever when running from Apache Zeppelin against AWS Athena

Tags: sql, apache-zeppelin, amazon-athena

I have created a zeppelin 'athena' interpreter (based on JDBC).

I have a very simple table named 'zeppelin_test' (it contains only 3 records)

The table includes 2 columns:

- name (string)
- age (int)

When I run the query below from Athena UI I get the result in ~ 2 seconds

```
SELECT name,age FROM "default"."zeppelin_test" limit 10;
```

When I run the query below from Zeppelin UI it runs forever.

I know that Zeppelin is able to connect to Athena because if I use a table that does not exists I get JDBC error.

I know the query is running with no issues since a csv file with the results is created under 'default.s3_staging_dir'.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Since you get an error for a bad query - I believe zeppelin can connect to Athena. After a successful query runs data is saved in S3. I believe the issue it there - please check that you configured "default.s3_staging_dir" to a directory with write access rights

Comment: As I said in the post - I am sure the query is running with no issues since I see a csv file ( query output ) generated at s3